# RVIZ is unable to show the map from hector_slam

Tags: rviz, hector-slam, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not have any errors. I am able to see the laserscan and it is able to detect and show the movement of the sensor. However, I am unable to see the map. I have put in the respective topics and fixed frames as many tutorials have mentioned. Can anyone help me check if anything is wrong? Thank you.

view_sick.launch file:

```
<launch>
<include file="$(find sick_tim)/launch/sick_tim551_2050001.launch" />
     
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find sick_tim)/ rviz/sick.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

hector_mapping_demo.launch file:

```
        <launch>
    <node pkg="hector

_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">
    <!-- Frame names -->
    <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
    <param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />
     
    <!-- Tf use -->
    <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
    
  

      <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
     
    <!-- Map size / start point -->
    <param name="map_resolution" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="map_size" value="2048"/>
<param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
<param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
<param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
<param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />



     <param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />
     
    <param name="map_pub_period" value="2" />
    <param name="laser_min_dist" value="0.4" />
<param name="laser_max_dist" value="5.5" />
<param name="output_timing" value="false" />
<param name="pub_map_scanmatch_transform" value="true" />
<!--<param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame" />-->
 

    <!-- Map update parameters -->
<param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
<param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.7" />    
<param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.2"/>
<param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
 
<!-- Advertising config --> 
    <param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>
    <param name**="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="5"/>
<param name="scan_topic" value="scan"/>
</node>
 
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 100"/>
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find hector_slam_launch)/rviz_cfg/mapping_demo.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

Command:

```
cd ~/catkin_make
catkin_make
roslaunch sick_tim view_sick.launch
roslaunch sick_tim hector_mapping_demo.launch

bag info:
path:        2018-10-18-11-51-00.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    31.8s
start:       Oct 18 2018 11:51:01.40 (1539834661.40)
end:         Oct 18 2018 11:51:33.15 (1539834693.15)
size:        79.0 MB
messages:    3253
compression: none [18/18 chunks]
types:       diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray         [60810da900de1dd6ddd437c3503511da]
             dynamic_reconfigure/Config              [958f16a05573709014982821e6822580]
             dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription   [757ce9d44ba8ddd801bb30bc456f946f]
             geometry_msgs/PoseStamped               [d3812c3cbc69362b77dc0b19b345f8f5]
             geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped [953b798c0f514ff060a53a3498ce6246]
             nav_msgs/MapMetaData                    [10cfc8a2818024d3248802c00c95f11b]
             nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid                  [3381f2d731d4076ec5c71b0759edbe4e]
             rosgraph_msgs/Log                       [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb]
             sensor_msgs/LaserScan                   [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]
             sensor_msgs/PointCloud                  [d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca]
             tf2_msgs/TFMessage                      [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]
topics:      /diagnostics                                    31 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray        
             /map                                            17 msgs    : nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid                 
             /map_metadata                                    1 msg     : nav_msgs/MapMetaData                   
             /poseupdate                                    479 msgs    : geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped
             /rosout                                         17 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log                       (5 connections)
             /rosout_agg                                      6 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log                      
             /scan                                          474 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan                  
             /sick_tim571_2050101/parameter_descriptions      1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription  
             /sick_tim571_2050101/parameter_updates           1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/Config             
             /slam_cloud                                    482 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud                 
             /slam_out_pose                                 474 msgs    : geometry_msgs/PoseStamped              
             /tf                                           1269 msgs    : tf2_msgs/TFMessage                      (2 connections)
             /tf_static

                                   1 msg     : tf2_msgs/TFMessage!
```

image description

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306404/rviz-is-unable-to-show-the-map-from-hector_slam/) by [rui](https://answers.ros.org/users/38136/rui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-22**:
Are they your actuals launch files ? I don't know if it's just typos but things like `<!**--` or `param name**=` would generate errors for sure.

**Comment by [rui](https://answers.ros.org/users/38136/rui/) on 2018-10-22**:
typo typo sry

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-22**:
You also launch rviz twice with the same name, which launch file are you actually using ?

**Comment by [rui](https://answers.ros.org/users/38136/rui/) on 2018-10-22**:
the bottom one

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2018-10-24**:
What do you get when you echo the map topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
  <arg name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" default="scanmatcher_frame"/>
  <arg name="base_frame" default="base_link"/>
  <arg name="odom_frame" default="base_link"/>
  <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" default="true"/>
  <arg name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" default="5"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/>
  <arg name="map_size" default="2048"/>
  
  <node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">
    
    <!-- Frame names -->
    <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
    <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" />
    <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame)" />
    
    <!-- Tf use -->
    <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
    <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="$(arg pub_map_odom_transform)"/>
    
    <!-- Map size / start point -->
    <param name="map_resolution" value="0.050"/>
    <param name="map_size" value="$(arg map_size)"/>
    <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
    <param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />
    
    <!-- Map update parameters -->
    <param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
    <param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.02" />
    <param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
    <param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />
    
    <!-- Advertising config --> 
    <param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>
    
    <param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="$(arg scan_subscriber_queue_size)"/>
    <param name="scan_topic" value="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    
    <!-- Debug parameters -->
    <!--
      <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>
      <param name="pub_drawings" value="true"/>
      <param name="pub_debug_output" value="true"/>
    -->
    <param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="$(arg tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name)" />
  </node>
    
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 30"/>
</launch>
```

This is my launch file. Maybe it can serve as a reference for your troubleshooting process.
It is working fine on RPLIDAR running with Raspberry Pi 3.

I am not sure this is your expected solution but due to the word limit in the comment section, I am unable to share with you my launch file. Therefore I reply as a solution.

Hopefully, it is useful for you.

---

Originally posted by [KinWah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38047/kinwah/) with karma: 91 on 2018-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rui](https://answers.ros.org/users/38136/rui/) on 2018-10-23**:
I am using raspberry pi 3 B+ may i ask which OpenGL config did you use?

**Comment by [KinWah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38047/kinwah/) on 2018-10-24**:
I think our project is slightly different.
my raspberry (slave) is just to publish laser data and the mapping is done on laptop (master).
I am not sure how to check opengl config :3 i am new to this.
but i use the default because as far as i remember, i did not change any of it.